# Using the same expression for EntityFramework queries and in-memory evaluation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

### The problem description

In my application, I have a search function that builds a complex search query based on user input on top of EntityFramework `DbSet` object and runs it against the database, something like this:

```
public static IQueryable<MyEntity> ApplySearchQuery(SearchSpec search, IQueryable<MyEntity> query)
{
    if (search.Condition1.HasValue)
        query = query.Where(e => e.SomeProperty == search.Condition1);
    if (search.Condition2.HasValue)
        query = query.Where(e => e.OtherProperty == search.Condition2);
    ....
}
```

This performs pretty well on the database side. Now I have come to a point that I have a single `MyEntity` at hand, and I want to see if a particular `SearchSpec` matches the entity or not. And I need to do this for a potentially large number of `SearchSpec` objects, so the performance is important.

I'd also really like to avoid duplicating the expressions.

### Here's what I've thought so far:

- I can call `Expression.Compile()` on the expressions to convert them to a delegate, and then call them. But since I have a parameter (the `search` parameter) I need to build expressions and compile them every time, making it a very inefficient way (I suppose, correct me if I'm wrong).
- I can wrap my single entity in an `IQueriable` using `new [] { myEntity }.AsQueriable()` and then evaluate the query on it. Not sure how well this will perform.

### The question:

- Which of the above approaches are faster?
- Is any of my assumptions (about the limitations) wrong?
- Is there any other way that I haven't thought about yet?

Comment: This approach - `new [] { myEntity }.AsQueriable()` - seems OK to me. At least, there no significant performance hit in transformation of single `myEntity` to `IQueryable<MyEntity>` from array.

Comment: @Dennis Yes, that's true. What I'm worried about is the way that underlying queryable is executed. For example, if the boolean conditions (expressions) are compiled and then executed for this, it makes it no better that the first approach.

Answer (score 0):

Here [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) could work miracles for you. With `PredicateBuilder` you can build an `Expression` that can be used against an `IQueryable`, but, when compiled, also against objects.

You could have a method that builds and returns the `Expression`

```
using LinqKit;

Expression<Func<MyEntity, bool>> CreateExpression(SearchSpec search)
{
    var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<MyEntity>();

    if (search.Condition1.HasValue)
        predicate = predicate.And(e => e.SomeProperty == search.Condition1);
    if (search.Condition2.HasValue)
        predicate = predicate.And(e => e.OtherProperty == search.Condition2);
    ...
    return predicate;
}
```

To be used as:

```
 var predicate = CreateExpression(search);
 var result = query.Where(predicate.Expand()); // will be translated into SQL.

 var match = predicate.Compile()(myEntity);
```

Notice the `Expand` call. Without it, EF will fail because under the hood `Invoke` will be called, which can't be translated into SQL. `Expand` replaces these calls so that EF can convert the expression to SQL.

Comment: This is interesting, thanks a lot, I learned a new lesson today. But still, it should be compiled for each of the search specs and I can't have a somehow cached compilation. (When matching in memory, I have a single entity and thousands of search specs)

Comment: Is this really a problem? Compiling and matching in memory should be really fast. Since you said it "performs pretty well on the database side", where many evaluations are executed and a round trip is made I would not expect any problems with in-memory evaluation of one object. I would be possible to restructure the expression as a chain of `where !search.Condition1.HasValue || e.SomeProperty == search.Condition1` etc. This would create one big expression, but the _whole_ expression would always be sent to the database (although the execution plan could be reused).